# What is $r$ in angular momentum quantization rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, atomic-physics, positronium

We know $$mvr= nh/2π $$ What is $r$ here if I consider **positronium** system.
I suppose it should be the radius of the orbit in which both are moving. But when I take the above equation and electrostatic equation of Coulomb's law I am getting the radius half of what it is actually. But if I take the value of $r=2r$ (that is the distance between both) I get   the correct radius.

- So is it correct to take $r$ as the distance between two? Or I got the answer as fluke?

Comment: Are you using reduced mass?

Comment: No, not using that...

Comment: You are applying the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) to positronium and this is not a correct description of the system. The ground state of positronium is an $S$ state and has zero orbital angular momentum.

Comment: What if I still want to apply it in hypothetical situation. How would I proceed?